# How to put url from DB onto the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Job model where I save a bunch of attributes, one of which is a link attribute as a string which contains a url to an external site. I want to put this link on my view but when I try to render it, it does not work.

Is there some reason that rails blocks urls from being shown? All my other attributes show up fine and when I try on rails console I can see the .link attribute showing up as a string.

Here is my link_to tag

`<%= link_to "Visit Website", job.link , class: "detail" %>`

The problem is that job.link does not even evaluate on the view. But it works on rails console.

My full code is below

Model:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.search(search)
        where("position LIKE ?", "%#{search}%") 
end

end
```

Controller:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController

  def index
      @jobs = Job.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10).search(params[:search])
  end

end
```

Job partial

```
<% if @jobs.present? %>
<div id="integration-list">
    <ul>
      <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
          <li>
                <div>
                  <a class="expand">
                      <div>
                          <h2 class="position"><%= job.position %> </h2>
                          <span class="info"> <%= job.company %> <br> Due Date: <%= job.date %></span>
                      </div>
                  </a>

                    <%= link_to "Visit Website", job.link , class: "detail" %>
                </div>
          </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
  <%= will_paginate @jobs, :class => 'jobsite_pagination' %>
</div>
```

There are no posts containing the term(s): .

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, use `job.link` instead of `#{job.link}`

```
<%= link_to "Visit Website", job.link , class: "detail" %>
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems like I just needed to restart the server to get it to work!